# JavaScript - JSDoc es6 class is displaying constructor as `new module:MyClass`

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have the current module `TextExtractor.js`, which exports a class `TextExtractor`:

```
/**
 * @file Extract RegEx matches from texts.
 * @author Victorio Molina <victoriomolinabermejo@gmail.com>
 * @license MIT
 * @category Lib
 * @subcategory Text Extractor
 * @module TextExtractor
 */

/**
 * Class for converting any text into Regex matches
 * and React props.
 *
 * @class
 */
export default class TextExtractor {
  /**
   * @param {string} text - The text to manipulate.
   * @param {DetectionOption[]} [detectionOptions=[]] - Detection options.
   */
  constructor(text, detectionOptions = []) {
    /**
     * Text that is being treated.
     *
     * @private
     * @type {string}
     */
    this.#text = text;

    /**
     * @private
     * @type {DetectionOption[]}
     * @default []
     */
    this.#detectionOptions = detectionOptions;
  }

  ...
}
```

For some reason, when I auto-generate the documentation using JSDoc, it displays the following:

> CLASS
>
> **module:TextExtractor**
>
> *module:TextExtractor(text, detectionOptions opt)*
>
> Class for converting any text into Regex matches and React props.

> CONSTRUCTOR
>
> ***new module:TextExtractor(text, detectionOptions opt)***

What JSDoc tag should I use to avoid displaying the class name as "module:TextExtractor"?

Is it the expected behavior?

Comment: I have also seen this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56133_01/2.7.0/jsdocs/module-classes_allPaths.html and it seems that is expected behavior? But... I don't know, it is not clean at all.

Comment: Also, the `@alias` tag seems to work, but it is moving all the code to the class section, leaving the module `modules/TextExtractor` clean (only with its own description), without referencing the respective class `classes/TextExtractor`.